# A compact Hausdorff space is metrizable if it is locally metrizable

Tags: general-topology

> A space $X$ is locally metrizable if each point $x$ of $X$ has a neighborhood that is metrizable in the subspace topology. Show that a compact Hausdorff space $X$ is metrizable if it is locally metrizable.
>
> **Hint:** Show that $X$ is a finite union of open subspaces, each of which has a countable basis.

I tried to use the fact of compact space. But I do not know if the opens are compact subspaces.

Comment: I tried to prove the hint: show that $X$ is a finite union of open subspaces, each of which has a countable basis.

Comment: I tried to use the fact of compact space. But i do not know if the opens are compacts subspaces.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, if $X$ is metrizable then it is also locally metrizable.

For the other direction, you could really follow the hint. Supposed that $X$ is locally metrizable, there exists an open cover $\bigcup_{x\in X}U_x$ of $X$ where $U_x$ is a metrizable neighborhood of $x$. Because of compactness, it has a finite subcover: $\bigcup_{i<n} U_i=X$ where $U_i:=U_{x_i}$ for some $x_i$.

Because of metrizability, each $U_i$ has countable base $(V_{i,j})_j$ of open subsets, so that all finite intersections of these are still countable, and they give a base of $X$.

The space also has to satisfy the separation axiom $T_3$, but this holds as $X$ is Hausdorff and compact.

Comment: The double implication was my misreading. Gone now.

Comment: Not every metrizable space has a countable base. Must all the compact ones?

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes.$\,$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, a clue?

Comment: @dfeuer: It’s Lindelöf, and in metrizable spaces Lindelöf, separable, and second countable are equivalent. You can get separability by taking for each $n\in\Bbb N$ the cover by open $2^{-n}$-balls, extracting a finite (or even just countable) subcover, and letting $D_n$ be the set of centres of the members of the subcover; $D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}D_n$ is a countable dense subset of $X$. Then $\{B(x,2^{-n}):x\in D\text{ and }n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable base for $X$.

Comment: but I do not know if open subspaces of a Lindeloff space is Lindeloff

Comment: $U_i$ should be closed to ensure.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks. I read the first sentence of your comment and figured it out.

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva, Prof. Scott's comment, that a metrizable space is Lindelöf iff it is secont countable, immediately implies that every Lindelöf metric space is hereditarily Lindelöf.

Comment: However, it's true some details remain missing.

Comment: After reading this several times, I'm still not sure why each $U_i$ is second countable.  These are open, metrizable subspaces of a compact Hausdorff space. We don't know these spaces are Lindelof.  dfeuer's last comment does seem to apply since we don't know that the entire space is metrizable.  That is, in fact, what is to be proven.  What am I missing?

Comment: you would not need finite intersections these right, just collection of these will work out

Answer (score 4):

For every $x\in X$, there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ which is metrizable. These neighborhoods cover $X$, i.e., $X=\bigcup_x U_x$. Now use the definition of compactness to reduce this to a finite union, $X=U_1\cup\ldots\cup U_n$. Each of these sets is metrizable, so pick metrics which are defined locally on each $U_i$. Lastly, use a partition of unity to patch together the local metrics into a global one.

Comment: Can you show construction of metric on $X\times X$ using Partition of unity. Means how metrices on $U_i$ can be patched up

Comment: @Sushil I don't think I understand your question.  Maybe you could elaborate.  Is your question: "Given a metrizable space $X$, show that $X\times X$ is metrizable." If so, this can be done without a partition of unity.  For example, on can define the metric on the product as $d_{X\times X}((x,y),(x',y'))=d_X(x,x')+d_X(y,y')$.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I don't get how partition of unity will help in getting metric.

Answer (score 0):

[Hint: Using normality/regularity]

The space $X$ is compact Hausdorff, so it is normal/regular.

Now for each $x\in X$, there is a metrizable  open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$, for this $U_{x}$, by regularity, there is an open neighborhood $V_{x}$ of $x$ such that
$x\in V_x \subset V_{x}^{-} \subset U_{x}$. Notice that the closure $V_x^{-}$ of $V_x$ is a closed subset of a compact space and a subspace of a metrizable space, therefore it is a compact metrizable space and has a countable basis, so $V_x$ has a countable basis.

Since $X$ is compact, and the family $\{V_x\}_{x\in X}$ of opens covers $X$, there is a finite subcover in which every member is open and has a countable basis. Hence $X$ has a countable basis.